# How do I optimise this SQL query

Tags: sql, optimization, count, distinct-values

I want to count the number of distinct users who have done a particular task and bin them into categories.

```
SELECT 
    u.`source_of_registration`, COUNT(DISTINCT u.users_id) , 
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.onboarding_statuses_id=4  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "KYC completed",
    SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(o.`created_at`,u.`created_at`)<=3 AND o.`onboarding_statuses_id`=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS "KYC completion TAT <3 days",
    SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(o.`created_at`,u.`created_at`)>3  AND o.`onboarding_statuses_id`=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS "KYC complation TAT >3 days",
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.onboarding_statuses_id=7  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "KYC verified",
    SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(o.`created_at`,u.`created_at`)<=3  AND o.`onboarding_statuses_id`=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS "KYC verification TAT <3 days",
    SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(o.`created_at`,u.`created_at`)>3  AND o.`onboarding_statuses_id`=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS "KYC verification TAT >3 days",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN i.`bank_connection_statuses_id`=1 THEN u.users_id ELSE NULL END) AS "BankConnected",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN  ex.users_id IN (SELECT u.users_id FROM users u WHERE u.created_at > "2020-07-31 00:00:00") OR l.users_id IN (SELECT u.users_id FROM users u WHERE u.created_at > "2020-07-31 00:00:00") THEN u.users_id ELSE NULL END )AS "F",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN datediff(ex.`created_at`,u.`created_at`)<=3 OR datediff(l.created_at,u.created_at)<=3 THEN u.users_id ELSE NULL END )AS "First trxn TAT < 3",
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN datediff(ex.`created_at`,u.`created_at`)>3 AND datediff(l.created_at,u.created_at)>3 THEN u.users_id ELSE NULL END )AS "First trxn TAT > 3"
FROM 
    users u USE INDEX(users_id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    `onboarding_status_histories` o ON u.users_id = o.users_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    companies c ON c.users_id = u.users_id 
LEFT JOIN   
    `external_fund_transfers` ex ON u.users_id = ex.users_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    `icici_connected_accounts` i ON i.users_id = u.users_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    `live_account_balance_histories` l ON l.users_id = u.users_id  
WHERE 
    u.created_at BETWEEN "2020-08-01 00:00:00" AND "2020-08-01 23:59:59" 
    AND u.`source_of_registration` IN ("m.bankonnect.co", "app.bankonnect.co") GROUP BY 
    `source_of_registration`
```

Comment: The only places for optimization of the query you posted above would be to add indices to cover the joins and where clause.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: You can try to use pivot.

Comment: @SK13 . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question.  Simplify the query that you have (fewer joins, fewer columns) but with a query that still has similar performance issues.  Then provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  Until then, try an index on `(created_at, source_of_registration)`.